# EmberJS Controller is undefined

Tags: javascript, ember.js, requirejs

So I started using EmberJS today.

```
// js/main.js
require.config({
    baseUrl:'js/',
    paths:{
        ember: 'libs/emberjs/ember-0.9.8.1',
        text: 'libs/require/text',
    }
});

// Start the main app logic.
requirejs([
        'ember',
        'app/controller/users'
    ],
    function(ember, UsersController) {
        App = Em.Application.create();
        console.log(UsersController); // undefined
    }
);

// My Controller
// js/app/controller/users.js
define('app/controllers/users', [
    'text!app/views/users/index.handlebar'
],
function( UsersIndexTemplate ) {
    return Ember.Object.create({
        indexView: Ember.View.create({
            template: Ember.Handlebars.compile( UsersIndexTemplate )
        }),
        // Activates the views and other initializations
        init: function() {
            this.get( 'indexView' ).appendTo( '#content' );
        }
    });
});
```

My question here is, why is the Controller undefined? I built this while reading the TodoMVC example and don't udnerstand why this doesn't work the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer, it's just too simple.

To invoke the main app logic I need to use `require()` NOT `requirejs()`